# WCF List<Stream> is creating own Stream:MarchalByRefObj type on client generated code

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am creating a WCF service for which I have to send a List as a Request,

```
[MessageContract]
public class DocumentMergerRequest
{
     [MessageHeader]
     public OutputDocumentFileFormat OutputFileFormat;
     [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
     public List<Stream> DocumentsToMerge;
}
```

The Stream is `System.IO.Stream` and when I try to use the service, the client generated code contains

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO")]
public partial class Stream : MarshalByRefObject {
}
```

The generated Stream is of type `MarshalByRefObject` instead of `System.IO.Stream`.

How can I fix this.

Comment: `Stream` is almost certainly the wrong type to be using here - what do you actually want to send between the server and client? If its "any arbitrary document", then `byte[]` might be the best fit.